# cocoa-Why there is an IBOutlet and a property that are of the same name?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm new to objective-c. When I'm reading some source code written by others, I encountered a problem.

I found that there is

```
    IBOutlet NSPopover *popover;
```

as well as

```
@property NSPopover *popover;
```

**PopoverViewController.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "TimerPopoverViewController.h"

@class TimerLogic;
@class TimerInfo;

@interface TimerPopoverDelegate : NSObject <NSPopoverDelegate> {
@private
    IBOutlet NSPopover *popover;
    IBOutlet NSWindow *detachWindow;
    IBOutlet TimerPopoverViewController *viewController;
}

@property NSPopover *popover;

- (void)showPopover:(id)sender timerInfo:(TimerInfo *)timerInfo;

@end
```

I think they are different variables. However, I can't figure out what do they do?

As far as I'm concerned, the `IBOutlet` is to show a popover. 
But what does the `@property` does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is either very old code or written in a very old (and now discouraged) style. The `IBOutlet` here is declaring an instance variable (ivar). The `@property` is declaring a property that is backed by the instance variable. In modern ObjC you should implement it this way:

**PopoverViewController.h**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@class TimerInfo;

// Things declared here are public
@interface TimerPopoverDelegate : NSObject <NSPopoverDelegate>

// You could leave this here if it is required by other parts of the program,
// but other parts of the program really shouldn't require it. See below.
// @property (nonatomic, readonly, weak) NSPopover *popover;

- (void)showPopover:(id)sender timerInfo:(TimerInfo *)timerInfo;

@end
```

**PopoverViewController.m**

```
// Generally avoid importing local headers into the .h unless you have to.
#import "TimerPopoverViewController.h"

// Things declared here are private. This is much better than the old @private.
@interface TimerPopoverDelegate ()
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, weak) IBOutlet NSPopover *popover;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *detachWindow;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, weak) IBOutlet TimerPopoverViewController *viewController;
@end
```

(Currently `popover` is public, but you should avoid exposing an `IBOutlet` that way. Outside objects should not directly touch a view controller's outlets.)

Comment: I noticed that the `IBOutlet` is put in `@private`. Does that matter? As I'm quite new to ObjC, I can hardly figure out what does `declaring a property that is backed by the instance variable` mean in your answer. Could you please give some hint? Thanks! :)

Comment: As a new ObjC developer, I wouldn't worry about it. Declaring instance variables this way is no longer necessary or appropriate. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html for current practice and how properties and ivars work together.